# Smaller font sizes in Winform's chart after exporting to file as picture

Tags: .net, vb.net, charts

The issue is related to smaller font sizes of different elements of a chart than on-screen after chart was exported to picture file or copied to clipboard. This makes chart's readability not good. I am using Visual Basic in VS2022 (latest update) with .Net Framework 4.7. The same problem exists in the latest .Net 7. In fact I realized that there is such a problem after I tried to migrate my app to .Net 7. Then I went back to my old app for .Net Framework 4.7 and realized that DpiAware settings were not set and thus my app looked a bit fuzzy when font size was 125% or 150%. I added following in app.config:

```
<add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
```

The result was the explained problem of smaller font sizes after export. Without the setting shown above exports were like on-screen. The only good thing now is that my app does not look fuzzy anymore.

The issue exists when I am using higher font sizes - 125% and 150% for resolution 1920 / 1080 on a single laptop monitor. The font sizes of the exported charts are the same as if I did the export with 100% font size.

I am developing in VS2022 with automatic scaling turned off. AutoScaleMode of all the forms in my app is set to 'DPI'.

Below is a comparison of the looks of both charts.
On-screen:
[image]

After export:

[image]

The piece of code used to export charts is below.

```
Private Sub SaveChartAsImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveChartAsImage.Click
    Dim myItem As ToolStripMenuItem = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim cms As ContextMenuStrip = CType(myItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

    Dim parentObject As Chart = Nothing
    Try
        parentObject = CType(Me.Controls.Find(cms.SourceControl.Name, True)(0), Chart)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    SupportingSubs.SaveChartAsImage(parentObject)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub SaveChartAsImage(ch As Chart)
    Dim SV As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
    Try
        Dim chName As String = ""
        chName = "Chart_" + ch.Titles(0).Text.Replace(" | ", "_")
        chName = chName.Replace("/", "_")
        SV.FileName = chName + ".png"
    Catch
    End Try

    SV.Filter = "PNG Image|*.png|JPeg Image|*.jpg"
    SV.FilterIndex = 1
    SV.RestoreDirectory = True

    Dim result As DialogResult = SV.ShowDialog()

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then

        If SV.FilterIndex = 1 Then
            ch.SaveImage(SV.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        ElseIf SV.FilterIndex = 2 Then
            ch.SaveImage(SV.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("File path does not exist.")
    End If
End Sub
```